# Embedded Viewing and Unsigned Documents

Tags: docusignapi

I was wondering if it is possible to have am embedded viewing of the documents, similar to do the embedded sending and signing but just documents viewing?

Also, after a document has been signed, is there anyway to see or download the unsigned copy that was used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not offer Embedded Viewing (other than Embedded Signing / Embedded Sending).

DocuSign only offers the current version of the envelope available through the API. If you want to see the origional document that was used, you will have to store this on your end.

Comment: There is kinda an embedded viewing, after the customer is done signing the envelope, the senders get a notification email saying that the document has been completed and a YEllow button with black fonts and when clicked, the sender is taken to that embedded view, is there a way to get that link?

Thanks.

Comment: There is not unfortuantly.

Comment: Once an embedded signer has signed, getting the Recipient View for that signer again and loading the URL will give you just a view of the document (because they have no action to take).  That can be a viable way to let someone view the document.